# Flutter SingleChildScrollView allow child overflow

Tags: flutter, overflow

Is there a way to allow the child of a SingleChildScrollView to overflow? I tried to use OverflowBox on the scroll view and did not work, and I tried using on the child and it crashed.

Comment: Have you tried using a Flexible as a SingleScrollView child?

Comment: got an error saying "Flexible widgets must be placed inside Flex widgets."

Comment: What do you mean by overflow? Can you show some example?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to allow overflow in the other direction of the scrolling direction of the

You can use a `OverflowBox` but it needs some properties:

```
OverflowBox(
    minHeight: 0,
    minWidth: 0,
    maxHeight: double.infinity,
    maxWidth: double.infinity,
    child: ...
),
```